# What is $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[\frac{1}{3n}, 1+\frac{1}{n})$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

What is $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[\frac{1}{3n}, 1+\frac{1}{n})$

So, just from thinking about it logically, I got $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[\frac{1}{3n}, 1+\frac{1}{n})=[\frac{1}{3}, 1)$.

However, I'm not sure about whether the bound on the right should be closed or open. Is $1$ included in this set or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $B_n = [\frac{1}{3n},1+\frac{1}{n}) = [\frac{1}{3n}, 1] \cup (1, 1 + \frac{1}{n})$. Then we have
$$\cap_{n=1}^\infty B_n = \left(\cap_{n=1}^\infty [\frac{1}{3n}, 1] \right) \cup \left( \cap_{n=1}^\infty (1, 1 + \frac{1}{n}) \right) = [\frac{1}{3}, 1]$$

Answer (score 0):

$1\in [1/3n, 1+1/n)$ for every $n\in \mathbb N.$